# Reversing numbers in C without using built in reverse function

Tags: c

I've been given a problem in class and to solve it I can't use the built in functions that already exist in c. It has to be an algorithm that performs the action. My function is below:

```
int reverseDigits(int userNumber)
{

    int rev1, rev2, rev3, rev4, reverseNumber;

    rev1 = userNumber/1000;

    rev2 = (userNumber - (rev1 * 1000)) / 100;

    rev3 = (userNumber - ((rev1 * 1000) + ( rev2 * 100))) / 10;

    rev4 = (userNumber - ((rev1 *1000) + (rev2 * 100) + (rev3 * 10))) / 1;


    if (rev1 == 0 && rev2 >= 1)
    {
        reverseNumber = ((rev2 *100) + (rev3 *10) + (rev1 * 1));
        return reverseNumber;
    }

    else if (rev2 == 0 && rev3 >= 1)
    {
        reverseNumber = ((rev3 * 10) + (rev1 * 1));
    }

    else if (rev3 == 0 && rev4 >= 1)
    {
        reverseNumber = (rev4 * 1);
    }

    else 
    {
        reverseNumber = ((rev4 * 1000) + (rev3 * 100) + (rev2 * 10) + (rev1 * 1));
        return reverseNumber;
    }


}
```

The function gets a user input and reverses it. My problem is that when given any number with less than 4 digits (It's only supposed to receive 4) the function returns them correctly but it adds zeros. For instance I send it 678 it will return 8760 or 57 would be 7500. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could first decide out of how many digits the input consists, which can be calculated by using the logarithm to base ten. This can be implemented by repeated division by 10.

Comment: Are you allowed to use recursive functions? Also, given `570` as input, is the expected output `075` or just `75`?

Comment: @RSahu Should be the same, as the return type is `int`.

Comment: That code will not produce the results you describe.    Also, all paths except the final `else` will "fall of the end" i.e. not execute a `return` statement.  Falling off the end causes the caller to have undefined behaviour if it uses the returned value.

Comment: Why OP accepted such a complex solution? This is really easy problem and could be solved by few lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the invalid set of if-else statements.

Using your approach the program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int reverseDigits( int userNumber )
{

    int rev1, rev2, rev3, rev4, reverseNumber;

    rev1 = userNumber / 1000;

    rev2 = ( userNumber - ( rev1 * 1000 ) ) / 100;

    rev3 = ( userNumber - ( ( rev1 * 1000 ) + ( rev2 * 100 ) ) ) / 10;

    rev4 = ( userNumber - ( ( rev1 * 1000 ) + ( rev2 * 100 ) + ( rev3 * 10 ) ) ) / 1;


    if ( rev1 != 0 )
    {
        reverseNumber = ( rev1 * 1 ) + ( rev2 * 10 ) + ( rev3 * 100 ) + ( rev4 * 1000 ); 
    }
    else if ( rev2 != 0 )
    {
        reverseNumber = ( rev2 * 1 ) + ( rev3 * 10 ) + ( rev4 * 100 ); 
    }
    else if ( rev3 != 0  )
    {
        reverseNumber = ( rev3 * 1 ) + ( rev4 * 10 ); 
    }
    else 
    {
        reverseNumber = ( rev4 * 1 ); 
    }

    return reverseNumber;

}

int main( void ) 
{
    for ( unsigned int x = 0, n = 1000; n != 0; n /= 10 )
    {
        x += n;
        printf( "%d\t%d\n", x,  reverseDigits( x ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1000    1
1100    11
1110    111
1111    1111
```

Answer (score 6):

This will work up to 9 digits.

```
int reverse(int num)
{
    int res = 0, tmp;
    while(num != 0)
    {
        tmp = num % 10;
        res = res*10 + tmp;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
int main()
{
    int num,i=0;
    scanf("%d",&num);

    int digit[4]={0};
    int num_digits=0;

    while(num!=0)
    {
         digit[num_digits] = num%10;
         num = num/10;
         num_digits++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<num_digits;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",digit[i]);
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

This can help you edit any number, with any number of digits. Just increase the array size of `digit`.

Edit :Iterator mistaked edited.

Comment: @AnatolyS that's c++ but the op asked for c. C++ != c.

Answer (score 0):

**Errors in posted code**

1. The computation under the first `if` clause is wrong. Instead of

   ```
   reverseNumber = ((rev2 *100) + (rev3 *10) + (rev1 * 1));
   ```

   it needs to be

   ```
   reverseNumber = ((rev4 *100) + (rev3 *10) + (rev2 * 1));
   ```
2. The computation under the first `else if` clause is wrong. Instead of

   ```
   reverseNumber = ((rev3 * 10) + (rev1 * 1));
   ```

   it needs to be

   ```
   reverseNumber = ((rev4 * 10) + (rev3 * 1));
   ```
3. You are missing `return` statements in the two `else if` clauses. As a consequence, if your program gets into those clauses, no `return` statement is executed and the program has undefined behavior. You can resolve that by removing the `return` statements you have now and adding a `return` statement at the end.

   ```
   if (rev1 == 0 && rev2 >= 1)
   {
      reverseNumber = ((rev4 *100) + (rev3 *10) + (rev2 * 1));
   }
   else if (rev2 == 0 && rev3 >= 1)
   {
      reverseNumber = ((rev4 * 10) + (rev3 * 1));
   }
   else if (rev3 == 0 && rev4 >= 1)
   {
      reverseNumber = (rev4 * 1);
   }
   else 
   {
      reverseNumber = ((rev4 * 1000) + (rev3 * 100) + (rev2 * 10) + (rev1 * 1));
   }
   return reverseNumber;
   ```

**A recursive solution**

If you are able to use recursive functions, you can use:

```
int reverseDigits2(int userNumber, int res)
{
   if ( userNumber == 0 )
   {
      return res;
   }

   return reverseDigits2(userNumber/10, 10*res + (userNumber%10)); 
}

int reverseDigits(int userNumber)
{
   return reverseDigits2(userNumber, 0);
}
```